# XMLStreamReader - Strange error

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

I have the following XML code

```
    <class name="ContentStreamer">
        <method name="sendAudio">
            <criteria>medium</criteria>
        </method>
        <method name="sendVideo">
            <criteria>weak</criteria>
        </method>
    </class>
```

I iterate over it with the following code (using XMLStreamReader)

```
if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
    String elementName = reader.getName().toString();
    if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("class")) {
        // get the class name and construct a Class
        classComposition = new ClassComposition();
        classComposition.setName(reader.getAttributeValue(0));
        System.out.println("***** Class: " + reader.getAttributeValue(0));
    } 
    else if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("method")) {
        MethodCriterion method = new MethodCriterion();
        method.setMethodName(reader.getAttributeValue(0));  
        System.out.println("***** Method: " + reader.getAttributeValue(0));
        // move forward and get the text from the '<criteria>' element
        reader.next();
        System.out.println("!!!" + reader.getName().toString());
    }
    else if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("criterion")) {
        return compositions;
    }
}
```

The output I get on the console is:

```
***** Class: ContentStreamer
***** Method: sendAudio
There was an error parsing the composition file
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal to call getName() when event type is CHARACTERS. Valid states are START_ELEMENT, END_ELEMENT
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getName(Unknown Source)
```

The area of the code that is giving me trouble is the last '`reader.next()`' and '`System.out.println`'.
I have replaced the '`reader.getName().toString()`' with '`reader.getElementText()`' as the '`<criteria>`' element is a text element only and the API says that this methods reads the text of a 'text-only element' (to quote). I have checked the event type using '`reader.getEventType()`' and it returns a 4, which corresponds to 'CHARACTERS'. So in that case, I tried '`reader.getText()`' and this just returns an empty string. I'm using Java 6. Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between `<method name="sendAudio">` and `<criteria>medium</criteria>`, you have a newline char and a number of spaces. These form a text node, and that's why you get `CHARACTERS` as the event type.

I'm surprised you got an empty string when calling `getText()`. Are you sure it wasn't a string with only a newline and space characters?

Comment: You're right. I completely overlooked them. Solution is to call 'reader.nextTag()' to skip the white space and then call 'reader.getElementText()' to get the text from '<criteria>'

Comment: Yep, this so called 'empty string' of mine was actually a 'crlf' with space characters.